# when using override on a collection<T> method, base class has ToCollection but derived class doesn't have

Tags: c#, asp.net

Base class:

```
public virtual Collection<string> GetPaymentMethods(Organization organization)
        {

 IPaymentService paymentService = ServiceLocator.GetPaymentService();

            Collection<PaymentMethod> paymentMethods = paymentService.GetPaymentMethods(organization.CountryCode, organization.LanguageCode, organization.UserType, AppAvailableType.AutoRenewal);
            return paymentMethods.Select(p => p.PaymentMethodType).ToCollection<string>();
        }
```

override:

```
 public override Collection<string> GetPaymentMethods(Organization organization)
        {

            Collection<PaymentMethod> paymentMethods = this.PaymentService.GetPaymentMethods(organization.CountryCode, organization.DisplayLanguageCode, organization.UserType, AppAvailableType.AutoRenewal);
            return paymentMethods.Select(p => p.PaymentMethodType).**ToCollection**<string>();

        }
```

In above method ".ToCollection" isn't available same as base class.Getting below error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ToCollection' and no extension method 'ToCollection' 
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Perhaps it's an [extension method](http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/tocollection-t) and the derived class isn't `using` the namespace that contains it?

Comment: Thanks for info . I added the namespace which the base class is using

Comment: @rajkumar - and did that solve the problem? Which namespaces? Where is ToCollection coming from?

Comment: yes i added our custom namepspace , which they wrote some extension methods . Its working now. ToCollection is coming from "public static Collection<T> ToCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)" method

Answer (score 1):

Go to base class, place the cursor over `ToCollection` method call. Press F12(Goto Definition). VS will show you where does the method comes from.

- If it is an extension method, then import the namespace in your derived class.
- If both are in different libraries and you don't have access in your library (for example the method is internal), you can't do anything about it.

Comment: i pressed F12 , it takes back to below method:

Comment: public static Collection<T> ToCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
        {

Comment: @rajkumar In which class this method is declared? What is the namespace of that class?

Comment: Thanks for info . I added the namespace which the base class is using

Answer (score 1):

IEnumerable doesn't contains any ToCollection methods. In your base class use extensions methods for convert to collection. Look on "uses" registration in your base class for find a necessary namespace which you should write in your derived class.

Comment: Thanks for info . I added the namespace which the base class is using